# Quick question about mod equation

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, modules

So here is the mod function:

$$5 ^ {31} \cdot 2 ^{789} - 23^{23}\pmod{10}$$

Is there a way to shorten it, or I must calculate it plain numbers? I have tried the mod powers rule, but except for the $23$ the others remain unchanged. It is strange because none of the known (to myself) mod rules fit.

Comment: $5\times 2 = 10 \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$. Now $23 \equiv 3\pmod{10}$. Try using Fermat's theorem.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan which of his theorems do you mean, because I am only aware of the Fermat`s last theorem and it doesn`t obviously suit here.I found Fermat`s little theorem, is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I meant Fermat's little theorem, by which I meant Euler's theorem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $3^2\equiv -1\pmod {10}$, one has

$$\begin{align}5^{31}\cdot 2^{789}-23^{23}&\equiv0-3^{23}\\&\equiv -(3^2)^{11}\cdot 3\\&\equiv -(-1)^{11}\cdot 3\\&\equiv -(-1)\cdot 3\\&\equiv 3.\end{align}$$

Comment: how you get that $5 ^{31} * 2^{789}$ mod 10 is 0?

Comment: @user4325010: $10=2\times 5$ divides $5^{31}\cdot 2^{789}$, so  $5^{31}\cdot 2^{789}\equiv 0\pmod{10}$.

Comment: is this also true in general cases? That when the bases are divided without remainder, the powers can be ignored? I am asking all those questions only to understand the pattern. However, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @user4325010: Yes, you are right. You may want to see the definition of mod.